# Android Device Verificaiton API with restricted API not working

Tags: android, api, console

I'm currently facing an issue : 
I want to use the **Android Device Verification API** through SafetyNet.
So I create an API Key in the Google Console API.

The thing is, It's only working when I use a non-restricted API Key (an API key that is not restricted to my Android App).
When I restrict the API Key, the result of my request is **500 internal error**

Inside the GoogleConsoleAPI, when I select "Create Credentials" then "Help Me Choose" and "What credentials should I use" for the Android Device Verification API. It says that I have already some API Key available but all of them are non-restricted API Key.. My restricted API Keys seems not to be available for this usage.

Do you have any ideas why ?

Thanks

Comment: Facing the same issue, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this personally and it works fine.
You can try the following -

1. Create Credentials
2. Add your SHA-1 and Package name while restrict to Android Apps
3. In "Restrict Keys" - restrict to only 1 api that is Android Device verification